# How to reduce time taken to read 40000 records in SQL DB hosted in a different region

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ado.net

I have a SP which fetches multiple result sets.
while iterating through the result set, one of the result gives 40000 records in result set.
Process of converting the result set to List , it takes couple of minutes to process the list, which is not desirable.

Is there a way to improve the way we can read data quicker, faster?

```
 var testEquipments = dataReader.GetList<TestEquipmentData>().ToList();

 public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(this DbDataReader reader) where T : new()
     {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var modelProperties = new List<string>();
        var columnList = reader.GetSchemaTable().Select().Select(r => r.ItemArray[0].ToString());
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var element = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
            IDictionary<string, string> databaseMappings = DBColumn<T>();
            string columnName;
            foreach (var f in properties)
            {
                if (!columnList.Contains(f.Name) && !databaseMappings.ContainsKey(f.Name))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                    
                columnName = databaseMappings.ContainsKey(f.Name) ? databaseMappings[f.Name] : f.Name;
                var o = (object)reader[columnName];

                if (o.GetType() != typeof(DBNull))
                {
                    f.SetValue(element, ChangeType(o, f.PropertyType), null);
                }
            }

            yield return element;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Do you really display a list of 40k records on one page? I'd recommend filtering data to have a result set with max 300 records.

Comment: Use EF Core, iso home made reflection code

Comment: Why `[entity-framework-core]` tag? You are not using anything from EF Core. What about performance, use some library (Dapper, EF Core etc.) for much faster materialization, and then see if the issue is from slow remove data retrieval over the wire.

Comment: @ErikEJ do you have some snippet, to do that?

Comment: @IvanStoev im fetching the data using [entity-framework-core] 
something like this in below
var dataReader = this.Database.ExecuteSqlReader("exec sp");

Comment: @Filburt im not uisng it for display purposes, but would like to use those 40k records for processing another module..

Comment: How much of the "couple of minutes" is CPU time?

Comment: First, EF Core has no such method. Second, processing `DbDataReader` with reflection has nothing to do with EF Core, EF or any other ORM or micro ORM. The shown reflection code is quite inefficient by itself, so is the reading/converting data reader values. Again, use some normal library to convert data reader result to objects, and then see what is the bottleneck.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? 40K rows is very little data. You could use EF to load a list of objects. Or you could use a micro-ORM like Dapper to get a list from any query, eg `var list=connection.Query<SomeType>("select.... where field1=@param1",new {param1=someValue);`

Comment: `dataReader = this.Database.ExecuteSqlReader("exec sp"); ` don't do that. You aren't using EF here, you're using ADO.NET. Use `FromSqlRaw` to have EF Core execute *and* map the data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos dataReader is fetching multiple result sets, one of the dataresult contains 40k records, and another one contains 60k records.

Comment: @IvanStoev   I tried using Dapper, still it takes 2min to execute (List<EquipmentData>)db.Query<EquipmentData>(query);

Comment: Well, at least now you know the bottleneck is not in the data materializing code. The bad news is that basically there is nothing more you can do as the culprit is transferring that data volume over the wire.

Answer (score 2):

1. evaluate columnList once instead of reevaluating it for every row
2. don't create databaseMappings for every row
3. don't use reflection
4. don't use linq

the first two are most important.
3. and 4. are ok as long as you do it once only and not in the loop.

hint: maybe check out dapper or something like that.

also ... don't select() twice to get the columnList?